# sample size for physical dimensions measurement of batch of mostly uniform physical objects required for statistic relevance

Tags: sampling

I wasn't quite sure how to title the question to make it as generic to the situation but as specific as possible.

Anyways, I work for a food factory and we are trying to compare different batches of raw materials from different suppliers. The raw material are de-shelled peanuts in this case. I have a 3 large bag of peanuts (25kg), each from a different supplier. I'm mostly concerned about the peanut average size and variance, so I am interested in measuring their length and width.

Each bag probably has tens of thousands of beans. How many peanuts from each batch should I measure for a statistically relevant comparison?

Comment: That depends on what difference in size you want to detect. For example, if you want to detect whether one bag of peanuts has peanuts that are twice the size of those in another bag, and if the size of the peanuts is not that different within each bag, then measuring just a few peanuts will do.

Comment: @Carl The size different is not that big. To the casual observer, they would be quite uniform. However, I would like to detect small visible differences, within millimetres. My end goal is to have a representative distribution chart  of the peanut widths for each batch, so the question is how many samples do I need to measure for a certain level of representation, or confidence.

Comment: Your question is simple enough, but there are confounding factors. Consider that if a bag of peanuts is vibrated, the larger ones will migrate to the top, especially if the peanuts in that bag vary in size. Also, If I were doing this problem frequently, I would use a vertical series of vibrating horizontal  gratings of decreasing grid size from top to bottom to do my measurements, and then count peanuts at each level. So, what kind of measurements are you doing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a drive-by question, it was asked for clarification to make an answer possible, which was not given. OP not seen for years